# Citing in PRL format

Tags: bibliographies

What is the easiest code to cite in PRL format. I was using the citation package apacite. Now i want to change it into PRL format. Is there any edasy way to do it?\
I tried using the rev4 package but it didn't work. I want the journal name in standard abbreviated format. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is “PRL” an acronym for “Physics Review Letters”? If not, what does the acronym stand for?

Comment: Physics Review Letters

Comment: @MIco In the reference section the journal name is shown in full form but I want the journal name in abbreviated form. How do I do it?

Comment: Change the `journal` field to `PRL`.

Comment: @Mico how to do that one?

Comment: Are you unsure how to edit a `.bib` file?

Comment: @Mico yes. how do i do it?

Comment: Since you’ve provided exactly zero information about how you administer your `.bib` file(s), and since my psychic abilities are worse than atrocious, I’m sadly not in a position to give meaningful advice on your follow-up query. May I suggest that you post a *new query*, in which you (a) state your specific objectives and (b) explain your current setup for how you generate `.bib` files?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495878/35864