# Citing in PRL format with abbreviated journal name

Tags: bibliographies

I want to cite in the Phyics Review Lettersformat with the journal name in abbreviated form.[image: This is the type of .bib entry that I have done]
How do i produce the journal name in abbreviated form for PRL format?

This is my .bib entry file

Comment: Please note that screenshots of your code are problematic for several reasons. They can pose accessibility issues for people with screen readers and they require everyone to copy the text manually if they want to run your code. Please provide a small, yet complete example document that shows which bibliography and citation packages you use along with an example `.bib` entry, so people can reproduce what you have so far: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: http://www.compholio.com/latex/jabbrv/

Comment: JabRef also has an extensive library of journal names and their abbreviations and lets you switch between the two.